# Von Mangoldt explicit formula for elliptic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $L = \sum a_n n^{-s} $ be the $L$-function of an elliptic curve $E$. I'm trying to get something similar to the von Mangoldt explicit formula that relates $\sum a_n$ with the residues of $\frac{L'}{L}\frac{x^s}{s}$. So far I have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}-\frac{L'}{L}\frac{x^s}{s}ds = x \text{rank}(E/\mathbb{Q}) - \frac{L'(0)}{L(0)} - \sum_{\rho \text{ nontrivial zero}} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho} - \frac{1}{2}\log(1-\frac{1}{x^2}) $$

The $x \text{rank}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ term is from assuming BSD. Is my math right? Can I evaluate the $\frac{L'(0)}{L(0)}$ term in any way?

Comment: Why not just write the coefficient of $x$ as ${\rm ord}_{s=1}(L(E,s))$ so you don't need to rely on BSD?  Also, why does your last term on the right have $1/x^2$ inside the logarithm?  The von Mangoldt explicit formula for $\zeta(s)$ has a term $-(1/2)\log(1-1/x^2)$ because the Gamma-factor for $\zeta(s)$ is $\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)$, which has (simple) poles at the negative *even* numbers and $0$, while the Gamma-factor for $L(E,s)$ is $(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)$, which has (simple) poles at *all* negative integers and $0$.  And are you aware that the terms $x^\rho/\rho$ have implicit coefficients?

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the help. I think I've misunderstood something with the Gamma-factor. I do know about the implicit coefficients and just wrote them the same way as with Chebyshev.